# MSI GE60 install Ubuntu along with Windows 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my MSI GE60 laptop, but it doesn't see my USB. In another PC I see them. I tried to but with UEFI CSM (compatibility support module) or something like that, but it doesn't work. I also updated my BIOS to the newest version .

I tried using Ubuntu tutorial, but nothing works for me.

EDIT I can boot grub in efi mode. (On efi-cms i cant boot from us)
Live cd dont boot but instead i see prompt.

```
grub>...
```

Edit x2 Ok it was invalid format maybe i need to format usb in fat instead of ntfs.
Edit x3 I see Install Ubuntu(or sth like that) but when i press enter i see black screen of nothigness.
And i have disabled secure boot and fast boot.

I think the only way is install in legacy and pray that it will works in someway. I spend on this too much time. I even write email to msi and ask them about this.

Edit x4 There is possiblity that uefi msi implemntation is preventing me from install ubuntu
https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=169082.0

I tried step by step what you said but it always end with black screen. I save option with F10(Ctrl=X doesnt work for me).

EDIT x5 I have 765m GTX maybe this will help you. 
Edit x6 I tried lubunt and it ends with black screen also
EDIT x7 I am accepting his answer but i am looking forward for better one. 
why because it my helps someone. I think even it can helps a lot of people. But I was looking for better answer.
Edit x8 Trying all possible distribution atm everyone like Debian(netinstall) ends with black screen.

Edit 9.

Arch is working but i dont want to install this from console mode it is to easy to break sth. And i dont have idead how to transform arch to ubuntu later.

Comment: More information on exactly what you tried. Step by step would be great.  Also any specific errors. As is, it is difficult to assist

Comment: I tried to follow this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI I made bootable usb with unetbootin. But my netbook only try to read and start windows. I tried uefi, uefi-cms(or sth like that), legacy. On legacy i only see partiton with efi. It is trying to read but dont boot my usb.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What does "it doesn't see" mean -- there are many tools that might be said to "see" a USB flash drive, and without clarification, this question is too vague to answer. As general advice, I recommend you read over my [page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for background information and general advice. Also, *do not* try to install in Compatibility Support Module (CSM) mode; that will just create new problems!

Comment: I set uefi mode and then in windows 8.1 i set boot from usb. And i see grub prompt but live cd dont start. It should start live usb. I dont knew what should i do at this moment.

Comment: USB flash drive should be formatted as FAT32. Look at the answers to this question at Ask Ubuntu Q&A: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Comment: I am reading this already. But i did everything. Next is to do some crazy magic in grub setting some flags and etc. It is very close to mess up evrything.

Comment: It's not "crazy magic". How to do it is in the answers to another question: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

Comment: Your Edit 4 was smart. I had a machine that wouldn't install Ubuntu. The Ubuntu installer just froze. I looked through the product forum and it said to use the RAID settings in the BIOS. But the machine didn't have RAID! So I tried changing the BIOS like it said in the product forum anyway and it worked.

Comment: Edit 5 really helped a lot. The power consumption of the GeForce GTX 765M GPU should be between 50 and 75 Watts! That's a lot of power and it could definitely make USB boot go to hell. The GPU has 3GB of built-in RAM. That could cause booting problems as well. Your GPU is sucking power from the USB flash drive. If you had a desktop instead of a laptop and you removed the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M and temporarily swapped in a cheapass graphics card, I bet it would boot like a champ. I also added more info about this to my answer.

Comment: Based on your Edit 9, I tried making a bootable minimal Ubuntu mini live USB by following the instructions on the Ubuntu Documentation Installation/Minimal CD wiki. I got this thing to boot to the Ubuntu installer on a machine that previously couldn't boot an Ubuntu live USB. This Ubuntu mini live USB can be used to install a complete working Ubuntu 13.10 + desktop environment on your laptop. I added the step-by-step instructions to my answer to your question on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to make a bootable USB flash drive with UNetbootin

In order to make an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu, use UNetbootin (Windows/Mac/Linux). The flash drive you use should be 2GB or larger, plus whatever additional space on the USB drive you want to use for persistent file storage, and formatted to FAT32. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the flash drive should be 4GB or larger. UNetbootin will automatically format the USB flash drive as FAT32 if it is not already formatted as FAT32. In either case the formatting procedure will delete all of the files that are already on the flash drive.

It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Ubuntu live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In Ubuntu you can find the device name of the flash drive using *Disk Utility* (or *Disks* if you are using Ubuntu 13.04 and later). In the picture below the name of the flash drive is `/dev/sdc1` where `/dev/sdc` is the device name of the flash drive and the 1 after sdc means UNetbootin will install the Ubuntu live USB on the first partition on that device.

[image]

In order to enable your computer to boot from the USB flash drive, you must enter your BIOS/UEFI setup utility by pressing one of these keys: Delete, F2 or F10 as soon as the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting. In the BIOS/UEFI menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new settings and exit the setup utility.

---

### Black screen

Look at the answers to this question at Ask Ubuntu Q&A: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

In particular this excerpt from one of the answers, by Jorge Castro, to the above question may be helpful:

Press F6, use the arrow keys to go down to `nomodeset`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. An *x* will appear to its left. Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "Try Ubuntu without installing."

[image]

You can also try `acpi = off` and `nolapic` if `nomodset` also shows up as a black screen.

---

### GRUB settings, flags, etc.

How to do it is in the answers to another question: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

---

### Concerning your hardware

The power consumption of the GeForce GTX 765M GPU should be between 50 and 75 Watts! That's a lot of power and it could definitely make USB boot go to hell. The GPU has 3GB of built-in RAM. That could cause booting problems as well. Your GPU could be sucking power from the USB flash drive. If the USB port is not getting enough power, then almost any live distro that you try to run from the USB will freeze.

And what's strange about it is that if the distro is really lightweight it WON'T freeze. GParted live USB won't freeze. Clonezilla live USB won't freeze. SOMETIMES Xubuntu live USB won't freeze (and sometimes it will freeze anyway) and also Lubuntu live USB. So maybe you can install a lightweight Ubuntu derivative and then build it back up into a decent Ubuntu desktop. This could be a lot of hard work though!

Comment: Can i later change lubuntu to ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, in fact I'll help you to do it if you register on Ask Ubuntu Q&A and ask your question there. It's a good question for there, because these new GPUs with 2GB or more RAM are causing a lot of Ubuntu live USB boot problems, and that means that a lot of people need to know about hacks like that to fix it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384590/install-ubuntu-along-with-windows-8-1-blackscreen